Can I buy Gulangyu ferry tickets outside China?
I'll be in Xiamen soon and would like to visit the island of Gulangyu. However, since this UNESCO World Heritage Site is extremely popular, access for non-residents of Xiamen is tightly controlled and if you rock up without a ticket, it's apparently not unusual to have to wait for hours to get a ferry.
The sole ferry operator is Xiamen Ferry (Chinese only), which sells tickets online for ¥35/person up to 10 days in advance. However, the site only accepts payments by Alipay/WeChat Pay and requires providing ID that will be checked on boarding. Also, while the T&C (Chinese only) suggests that foreign passports are accepted as ID, this random post on Tripadvisor says getting a confirmation requires a local Chinese phone number.
TL;DR: Is it possible to buy Gulangyu ferry tickets from outside China, without a Chinese phone number? Happy to pay a reasonable premium to a travel agent/reseller if needed, but I don't want to fork out for a guided tour etc.

Although I've visited several islands where cars and motorcycles are banned, I don't think I've ever come across a place where bicycles are banned as well.

Not really an answer, but: The ID requirements for tourist attractions (and also for trains) in China is usually a Chinese ID card number or, for foreigners, the passport number. The phone number thing that is mentioned in the TripAdvisor post is a separate issue. It is also hearsay and the info seems to be more than a year old. Accessability to Chinese online services for foreigners has improved a lot over the last year, so this may or may not be really true / really true anymore.

Also please check really carefully whenever you enter your passport number anywhere because a mistyped number may mean you get turned back.
